# Is there a way to stop Eclipse from generating a new run-configuration everytime I restart my GAE App?

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, pydev

Normally I restart my GAE application by right-clicking on the project and then I choose Pydev: Google App-Engine Run.

I've noticed that every time I do this it generates a new run-configuration even though nothing much has changed. Over a few days of work a whole bunch of these useless configuration objects could be created. It's annoying not just because of the clutter but also because any settings I put into the first run-configuration do not get carried forwards into the subsequently created configurations.

I found one work-around which is that I can add it to the run-menu via the "common" tab (the green circle play-button at the top of the screen).

I'd prefer to find a way to stop Eclipse needlessly generating a new run-configuration when I recycle the project. Even better would be a method to hot-key restart (e.g. pressing <kbd>F9</kbd>). Can anybody suggest a way of removing this nuisance feature of my IDE?

FYI, I'm using the very latest Eclipse on Windows 32bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The run as will really create a new run configuration... Just erase the bunch of configurations you have, run it once and edit that one.

Later ( if you followed the suggestion on http://pydev.org/manual_101_run.html to configure Ctrl+F11 to always relaunch last launch ), you should be able to Ctrl+F11 to rerun the last launch done (or choose it from the menu: run > run history > previous launches: can be accessed through Alt+R, T, number of config).